# Using a function-generated column in the where clause

Tags: sql, function, virtual-column

I have an SQL query, which calls a stored SQL function, I want to do this:

```
SELECT    dbo.fn_is_current('''{round}''', r.fund_cd, r.rnd) as [current]
FROM      BLAH
WHERE     current = 1
```

The select works fine, however, it doesn't know "current". Even though (without the WHERE) the data it generates does have the "current" column, and it's correct.

So, I'm assuming that this is a notation issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an alias from the `select` in the `where` clause (or even again in the same `select`).  Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT dbo.fn_is_current('''{round}''', r.fund_cd, r.rnd) as [current]
      FROM BLAH
     ) t
WHERE [current] = 1;
```

As a note:  `current` is a very bad name for a column because it is a reserved word (in many databases at least, including SQL Server).  The word is used when defining cursors.  Use something else, such as `currval`.

Comment: Thanks! Current is actually the name of the column we need (it's for "is this row current data, or historical data?") But thanks, I'll try to keep that at a minimum...